# Chronicle Queue Proxy Method Value is Same Object Instance Each Time

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I'm using Chronicle V4 proxy API to convert a message into a function call.

When `myMethod(Thing a)` is invoked after a `readOne()` call, the `'a'` object instance ID is the same each time but the content has the latest state.

Imagine:

```
readOne();
readOne();
```

Methods fired:

```
myMethod(Thing a)
myMethod(Thing a)
```

The second call with param `'a'` now with different state overrides any previous caches version of `'a'` in say a hashmap in memory, because the java object instance ID is the **same one** when myMethod was invoked initially.

I'm hoping this is some odd in my setup - be good to know if this is by design or just an issue my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design to provide implicit recycling of the object.

If you want a new object you can use `Marshallable.deepCopy()` or use `Marshallable.copyTo()` an existing one.  Unless you retain the object, there shouldn't be an issue. If you write it out to another queue, for example, it is written immediately rather than in the background.

It is implemented this way so you can process millions of events and create very few objects. i.e. less than 1 byte of garbage per message.

I highly recommend using the latest version of Queue https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:net.openhft%20AND%20a:chronicle-queue currently v5.17.4

Comment: Thanks, really helpful info.  If using a Chr Map Disk storage instead of in-memory, is deepCopy still required since it's off-heap?

Comment: If you want to copy to/from CMap, a copy will need to be made. If you get a DTO via a `MethodReader` and do `Map.put(key, dto)` it will do this implicitly. BTW This doesn't have to create any objects doing this even for nested data structures.

Comment: I assume there is an overhead to pay when calling Map.get(..) and deserializing the value from disk compared to the in-memory option? Interesting to know that it can save massively on object creation using the CQu and CMap combination in that way.

Comment: @JARC There is another method, `getUsing` where you pass an existing object to be populated. If the object is large, using Chronicle-Values can improve performance as it doesn't actually serialize or deserialize the object, rather it places a flyweight struct over the memory and allows you to access it like a POJO. e.g. you can update just one field of a large object and only that field is touched.